# Properties of SPD Matrix Norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

***Question:***
Let $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  be two symmetric and positive definite matrices with $AB=BA$ and $\left(A\underline{x},\underline{x}\right)\geq\left(B\underline{x},\underline{x}\right)\,\,\forall\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Prove that $\left\Vert A\underline{x}\right\Vert _{2}\geq\left\Vert B\underline{x}\right\Vert _{2}\forall\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$.The symbols denote the Euclidean inner product and the Euclidean vector norm.

***My attempt (probably not very good)***

Consider $\lambda_{i}$ as the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ and $v_{i}$ as the eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_{i}$. Since $A$ is symmetric positive definite, its eigenvalues are all positive . Therefore, we get the following:

$Av_{i} =\lambda_{i}v_{i}
 $

$A\underline{x}=\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\lambda_{i}v_{i}\underline{x}_{i}\right)\\$

We get the same for the matrix B when we consider $\mu_{i}$ and $u_{i}$ to be the eigenvalues and eigenvectors respectively giving us the following:

$Bu_{i}=\mu_{i}u_{i}\\$

$B\underline{x}=\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\mu_{i}u_{i}\underline{x}_{i}\right)\\$

Now we consider the inequality from the question
\begin{align*}
\left(A\underline{x},\underline{x}\right) & \geq\left(B\underline{x},\underline{x}\right)\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\left(A\underline{x},\underline{x}\right)-\left(B\underline{x},\underline{x}\right) & \geq0\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\left(\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\lambda_{i}v_{i}\underline{x}_{i}\right),\underline{x}\right)-\left(\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\mu_{i}u_{i}\underline{x}_{i}\right),\underline{x}\right) & \geq0\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\left(\underset{i}{\sum}\lambda_{i}\left(v_{i}\underline{x}_{i},\underline{x}\right)\right)-\left(\underset{i}{\sum}\mu_{i}\left(u_{i}\underline{x}_{i},\underline{x}\right)\right) & \geq0\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\underset{i}{\sum}\lambda_{i}\left(v_{i}\underline{x}_{i},\underline{x}\right)-\mu_{i}\left(u_{i}\underline{x}_{i},\underline{x}\right) & \geq0\\
\end{align*}

Since both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric we are able to simplify their
inner products as such:

\begin{align*}
\left(v_{i}\underline{x}_{i},\underline{x}\right) & =\left(\underline{x}_{i},v_{i}\underline{x}\right)=\left(\underline{x}_{i},v_{i}\right)^{T}\underline{x}\\
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\left(u_{i}\underline{x}_{i},\underline{x}\right) & =\left(\underline{x}_{i},u_{i}\underline{x}\right)=\left(\underline{x}_{i},u_{i}\right)^{T}\underline{x}\\
\end{align*}

We now substitute this into the above inequality to obtain the following:

\begin{align*}
\underset{i}{\sum}\lambda_{i}\left(\left(\underline{x}_{i},v_{i}\right)^{T}\underline{x}\right)-\mu_{i}\left(\left(\underline{x}_{i},u_{i}\right)^{T}\underline{x}\right) & \geq0\\
\end{align*}

Simplifying, we have :

\begin{align*}
\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\left(\lambda_{i}-\mu_{i}\right)\left(\underline{x}_{i},v_{i}-u_{i}\right)^{T}\underline{x}\right) & \geq0\\
\end{align*}

Since $\left(\underline{x}_{i},v_{i}-u_{i}\right)^{T}$ is a scalar,
we are able to rewrite the inequality as follows:

\begin{align*}
\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\left(\lambda_{i}-\mu_{i}\right)\left(\underline{x}_{i},v_{i}-u_{i}\right)^{T}\right)\underline{x} & \geq0\\
\end{align*}

Now consider some vector $\underline{y}=\underset{i}{\sum}\underline{x}_{i}\left(v_{i}-u_{i}\right),$a
linear combination of the differences between the eigenvectors of
A and B, weighted by the components of $\underline{x}$.

Notice that we can rewrite this as $\underline{y}^{T}\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\lambda_{i}-\mu_{i}\right)\underline{y}\geq0$.

Since both $A$ and $B$ are SPD, we know $\lambda_{i},\mu_{i}>0$
we find that $\lambda_{i}-\mu_{i}>0\,\,\forall i$. As a result, we
can say that $\underset{i}{\sum}\left(\lambda_{i}-\mu_{i}\right)$
is some scalar that we will denote as $\kappa$.

Therefore we have $\underline{y}^{T}\kappa\underline{y}\geq0$.

Further, since $\kappa>0$ and $\underline{y}$ is a non-zero vector,
we can conclude that $\underline{y}^{T}\kappa\underline{y}>0$

Finally, we consider the norms:

\begin{align*}
\left\Vert A\underline{x}\right\Vert _{2} & =\left\Vert \underset{i}{\sum}\left(\lambda_{i}v_{i}\underline{x}_{i}\right)\right\Vert _{2}=\left\Vert \underline{y}\right\Vert _{2}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\left\Vert B\underline{x}\right\Vert _{2} & =\left\Vert \underset{i}{\sum}\left(\mu_{i}u_{i}\underline{x}_{i}\right)\right\Vert _{2}\\
\end{align*}

Since $\underline{y}$ is a non-zero vector and $\left\Vert \underline{y}\right\Vert _{2}>0$,
we conclude $\left\Vert A\underline{x}\right\Vert _{2}\geq\left\Vert B\underline{x}\right\Vert _{2}\forall\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: You did multiple mistakes. The first one you consider that $\underline x_i$ is vector but it is a  scalar.

Comment: Besides do you the square root of a matrix?

Answer (score 2):

**First proof** The result is true for bounded positive and commuting operators on a Hilbert space. The assumption is equivalent to $\|A^{1/2}y\|\ge \|B^{1/2}y\|.$ Hence$$ \|Ax\|\ge \|B^{1/2}A^{1/2}x\|=\|A^{1/2}B^{1/2}x\|\ge \|Bx\|$$

**Another proof** In the finite dimensional case let $V_\lambda$ denote the subspace of all eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda.$ Then $B(V_\lambda)\subset V_\lambda.$ Indeed for $v\in V_\lambda $ we have
$$ABv=BAv=\lambda Bv$$ The entire space is the orthogonal sum of subspaces $V_{\lambda}$ corresponding to the eigenvalues of $A.$ It suffices to show the inequality for $x\in V_\lambda.$ By assumptions we have $$\lambda \|x\|^2=\langle Ax,x\rangle \ge  \langle Bx,x\rangle$$ Therefore the eigenvalues of $B$ restricted to $V_\lambda$ are nonnegative and less than $\lambda.$ Hence the operator norm of $B$ restricted to $V_\lambda$ is less than or equal $\lambda.$ Therefore $$\|Bx\|\le \lambda \|x\|=\|Ax\|$$